# Fetching common elements in admin layout

Tags: cakephp, element, admin, block, fetch

I'm trying to fetch a common element from my admin.ctp layout

```
<?php echo $this->fetch('my_element'); ?>
```

This functions is working properly in my default layout but is returning an empty string if called from my admin layout.

I'm using admin routing prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this form:

```
<?php echo $this->element('my_element'); ?>
```